# How do I make it such that the result of a query is partitioned as the input?

Tags: hive, hiveql, create-table, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I'm a newbie on hive, so a basic question: How do I create a query such that the result of that query is partitioned in a specific way?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_x (
 x SMALLINT,
 y FLOAT)
PARTITIONED BY (id SMALLINT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS ORC;

INSERT INTO TABLE `tbl_x` 
VALUES (1, 1, 1.0),
       (1, 1, 2.0),
       (1, 2, 3.0),
       (1, 2, 4.0),
       (2, 1, 5.0),
       (2, 1, 6.0),
       (2, 2, 7.0),
       (2, 2, 8.0);

CREATE TABLE tbl_y AS SELECT `id`, `x`, SUM(`y`) AS `y_sum`
FROM `tbl_x`
GROUP BY `id`, `x`;
```

In that example, I'd like tbl_y to be partitioned too.

Trying this *doesn't* work:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_y AS SELECT `id`, `x`, SUM(`y`) AS `y_sum`
FROM `tbl_x`
GROUP BY `id`, `x` PARTITIONED BY (id SMALLINT);
```

What is the trick here? Should I define the partitioned table first and insert the results in?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CTAS with Dynamic Partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241648/ctas-with-dynamic-partition)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should create a partitioned table separately. Create partitioned table as select (CTAS) is not supported.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_y(x smallint,y_sum double)
partitioned by (id smallint)
STORED AS ORC;
```

If the table schema is the same, you can use [**CREATE LIKE**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableLike):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_y like tbl_x;
```

You also can use `DISTRIBUTE BY` to distribute the data evenly between reducers, see this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38475807/2700344

```
insert overwrite table tbl_y partition(id)
select id, x, SUM(y) AS y_sum
fromtbl_x
group by id, x 
distribute by id, FLOOR(RAND()*100.0)%20;
```

Comment: Thanks. I think there's a typo there on the DISTRIBUTE bit, since you added it twice. I also got this error: `Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20190405103559_37aabd69-88dc-4137-8289-aa35357e1385); Time taken: 25.555 seconds
Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask (state=08S01,code=1)`

Comment: @LeoBarlach This is not informative. Dig Job tracker logs of failed container.